# How to make a thread to wait for another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I just cannot make my thread for wait for another. I have a thread and a ExcecutorService with N threads.
Depending on 50-50% chance I need to start a thread. How can I make my Asistent Thread to stop with submiting until previous thread is finished?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class UceniciThread implements Runnable{


    ExecutorService studenti;
    CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    int n;

    public UceniciThread(ExecutorService studenti, int n){
        this.studenti = studenti;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Random r = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

            boolean sansa = r.nextBoolean();

            if (sansa) {

            studenti.submit(new Thread(new Asistent()));

            } else {

            studenti.submit(new Thread(new Profesor(barrier)));

            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: You need these conditions with any arbitrary `ExecutorService`, or do you control which `ExecutorService` is used? You can define a single-threaded executor, which would only run a single thread at a time (off of the main thread). Otherwise, there's `Thread#join` or `#wait`/`#yeild`. By the way, you don't submit a `new Thread` to `ExecutorService` (which expects a `Runnable`), since the service will just end up using the `#run` method for it anyhow (which in turn will use your passed-in Runnable's `#run` method).

Comment: Does each Asistent need to wait for both the previous Asistent and the previous Profesor tasks to complete?  Or does an Asistent just need to wait for the previous Asistent, even while a Profesor task may be in progress?

Comment: Executor service works by giving it a task to execute. The executor service interface does not specify how those tasks will be executed. (in what thread, in what order etc.) -- [this is an execution policy defined by providing an implementation for the ExecutorService interface for the required behavior], When you provide a task to submit method, it returns an instance of Future on which you could call get(). The get method of feature will wait until the task you submitted finishes. (successfully or throw an exception). Hence, you could use the reference given by submit to wait to finish.

Comment: Moreover, you should use Runnable or Callable interface to define tasks. Although Thread class implements Runnable, you should not create an instance of Thread class just to give a runnable to an ExecutorService. ExecutorService creates, removes threads as required depending on its implementation. A typical implementation used is ThreadPoolExecutor which provides different configuration options.  Static methods in Executors which is used to create thread pools use the ThreadPoolExecutor class and configure it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make my Asistent Thread to stop with submiting until previous thread is finished?

You would have to hold a reference to the "previous thread" and make sure it's finished before proceeding.

Thread has a [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) method that blocks until the thread is done, while [submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) returns a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which has a [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) method that blocks until the underlying thread is done.

Use one of these methods to block before continuing to submit a new Asistent Thread.